# Android Studio find xml data file by name

Tags: android, xml

the problem is that I have various XML files with the data that I need for my app and I want to access to read them by the name of the XML file: "fileName.xml" so I can run the pull parser. Since the program only knows which file to load by its name which is given by a string I can't call them using `r.id.fileName.xml`.

I have tried things like:

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("r.id.fileName", "id", getPackageName());
```

and then call it by this resID... but it doesn't seem to work (resID is always 0)  :(

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution from a performance standpoint is to have a mapping in your Java code between some string and the resource ID value:

```
private static HashMap<String, Integer> RESOURCES=new HashMap<>();

static {
  RESOURCES.put("thingy", R.xml.thingy);
  RESOURCES.put("thingy2", R.xml.thingy2);
  // and so on
}
```

Then, you can just call `RESOURCES.get()` to retrieve the ID value, without having to use the reflection that goes on inside of `getIdentifier()`.

If you really want to use `getIdentifier()`, then the syntax would be:

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("fileName", "xml", getPackageName());
```

because:

- the first parameter is the base name of the resource
- the second parameter is the type of the resource, and the files in `res/xml/` are not `id` resources